# Magento 2 : How to Load a Cms Block and Set Custom Variable Values

Tags: magento2, static-block, custom-variable, attribute-value

I created cms block with custom variable name 'redemption'. I wanted to load cms block, pass and replace value to custom variable 'redemption'.

Please help, It's Urgent.

Comment: Your custom attribute is created via setup script? It belongs to `cms_block` table?

Comment: I created  my custom variable through magento admin panel  system->custom variables.